# Masu stem to connect sentences

Tags: grammar, renyōkei

When using masu-stem to connect sentences, is the short form for shimashita = shi?

> 昨日無事に大学を卒業しました。日曜日に国へ帰ります。

=

> 昨日無事に大学を卒業し、日曜日に国へ帰ります。

Is his correct?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, your sentence is correct; you can connect sentences with the continuative form (連用形) of verbs, and here in your example you can use し, which is the continuative form of the verb する.

> 昨日無事に大学を卒業**し**、日曜日に国へ帰ります。

You can also use the te-form して:

> 昨日無事に大学を卒業**して**、日曜日に国へ帰ります。

<sub>（The continuative form 「～し、…」 sounds a bit more literary/formal and less casual/conversational than the te-form 「～して、…」）</sub>

---

A few examples:

> - ネットで注文**し**購入する (≂ 注文し**て**)
> - よく学**び**よく遊べ (≂ 学ん**で**)
> - 子供を産**み**育てる (≂ 産ん**で**)

<sub>As a side note: When the continuative form is one mora, eg 「[得]{え}」「寝」「見」「[来]{き}」「[出]{で}」「い(居)」, using the te-form is more common / preferred: 「～を**得て**、...」「早めに**寝て**、...」「～を**見て**、...」「～に**来て** 、...」「～に**いて**、...」 etc., over 「～を得、...」「早めに寝、...」「～を見、...」「～に来、...」 etc.  (「～に[居]{い}、...」 sounds unnatural.)　But 「XXし、...」 sounds natural and is commonly used.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

"do the short form for shimashita=shi?"
No. There is no short form for しました because it is the opposite: しました comes from し + ました, し being the short form.

dictionary form: する
short form: し
formal: short form + ます =  します.
past: short form + ました = しました

Another example:
dictionary form: 書く
short form: 書き
formal: 書き + ます =  書きます.
past: 書き + ました = 書きました

That is why there is no short form for しました. You use the short form to create しました, not the other way around.