# How do you handle multiple verbs in this situation?

Tags: grammar

From what I understand, the final verb determines the reference time of the sentence, but I'm a little confused on how to handle the sequence of verbs with the たりする construction here (particularly after following a stem of another verb):

> カラカラと氷を鳴らしながら、彼女は麦茶に口をつけ、グラスの側面を頬に当てたりもしていた

The way I'm interpreting it, 口をつけ is seen as the verb in focus, while たりもしていた is simply listing any action(s) done alongside with it. But when considering ながら here, it becomes even more confusing how to make sense of the order here. Can someone provide clarification, or possibly correct any misunderstandings I might have. Thank you.

Comment: Is it normal for verb + らし to be followed by ながら at the start of a sentence; like in your own?

Comment: What do you mean? 鳴らし is just the 連用形 of 鳴らす, followed by the particle ながら. Usage wise, I did a little digging and found another similar usage (in the same work):
ビー玉をカラカラと鳴らしながら、喉の渇きを癒す
Googling gave plenty of results, too.

Comment: Nothing really, just noticing that in most cases I've encountered verb + らし, its 90% of the time followed by the particle ながら and located at the end of the first sentence section before the comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a suitable translation would be:

> While rattling around the ice, she tasted the barley tea and even did things like pressing the side of the glass against her cheek.

If I were actually translating this, I'd probably omit the "did things like". It is implied in the Japanese but it's somewhat unnatural to include it in English when only 1 example is cited.

つけ is the 連用形{れんようけい} (masu stem) of つける. In written Japanese, the 連用形 can be used to join independent clauses in the same manner as the te-form. In this case, it is showing that the actions happened sequentially. Both つけ and していた are of equal priority.

I do not believe it is clear in the Japanese whether she was rattling the ice as she pressed it to her cheek or if the rattling only coincides with tasting.

See: [Masu stem to connecting sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41133/masu-stem-to-connecting-sentences)

Answer (score 3):

> カラカラと氷を鳴らしながら、彼女は麦茶に口をつけ、グラスの側面を頬に当てたりもしていた

順番に分析します。

1. 「麦茶に口をつけ」は、「コップに入った麦茶を飲む」という意味ですが、一度に飲む量は「少量」でかつ「静か」に飲むという意味です。しかも「立て続けに」飲むのではなく、「休み休み」飲みます。
2. 「静かに」「少量を」「休み休み」飲んでいますので、「グラスに入った氷をカラカラと鳴らし」て余暇｛よか｝を潰{つぶ}しているか、余暇を楽しんでいることが分かると同時に、氷のグラスにぶつかる音が聞こえるほど「静か」だということも良く分かります。
3. 「カラカラと氷を鳴らし**ながら**」と書かれていますので、氷を鳴らすときは、必ずお茶を飲むことが分かります。しかし、その逆は書かれておりません。すなわち、「麦茶を飲むときは必ず氷を鳴らす」とは限りません。
   頻度で言うと「グラスに口をつける＝麦茶を飲む」≧「カラカラと氷を鳴らす」
   むろん、この人は暇でしょうから、「グラスに入った氷をカラカラと鳴らす」だけの行為は考えられますが、その数は頻度に入れておりません。
4. 最後の「グラスの側面を頬に当て**たり**もしていた」は、「カラカラと氷を鳴らす」回数に比べてずっと少ないが「そのようなこと」（＝「グラスの側面を頬に当てる」ようなこと）も「時にはしていた」と言う意味です。
5. 「グラスの側面を頬に当て**たり**もしていた」のもう一つのニュアンスは「頬にグラスを当てるようなことは普通ならしないが、この人はした」というほど、「余程他にすることがないのだな」あるいは「他に時間をつぶす方法がないのだな」というニュアンスも感じられます。
   ご存知のように「氷入りの麦茶が入ったグラス」の側面は結露｛けつろ｝していますので、頬に当てるとひんやりするでしょうが、大人の人がすると行儀｛ぎょうぎ｝が悪いので、余り他人の居るところではしません。従って、この人は一人切りで麦茶を飲んでいるか、余り人目のつかないところで麦茶を飲んでいることも分かります。そして、グラスに入っている氷を鳴らしたり、結露したグラスを頬に当てるなど、余程時間を持て余していることが確実です。

最初の文で記述されている事象の頻度を整理すると次のようになります。
「一般に、喉｛のど｝が渇｛かわ｝いているときに麦茶をのむ」＞「グラスに口をつける＝麦茶を飲む」≧「カラカラと氷を鳴らす」≫「グラスの側面を頬に当てる」

最初の文を書き換えると次のようになると思います。

> カラカラと氷を鳴らしながら、彼女は麦茶に口をつけていた。そして、時には、グラスの側面を頬に当てるようなこともあった。

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you mean. "While shaking around the ice, she did things like taste the tea, and apply it to her cheek."

What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: So you're saying 口をつけ is part of the sequence たりもしていた?

Comment: I just don't understand what you mean by sequence. Yes, it is all connected, as 口をつけ is a continuing form like the te-form, but this is commonly called the masu stem (as the other user said, the 連用形), so it then connects to the following final verb, or rather the entire たりもする structure.