# What is the grammar explanation for 高くなり?

Tags: conjugations

I'm trying to make sense of this sentence:

> 一寸法師の背が高くなり立派な青年になりました

It's from the 一寸法師 story.

I don't understand the word 高くなり. It seems so be takakunarimasu, the same inflection but without the masu suffix.

Is that right? Is there any book that explains this? In the same story there are other expressions with verbs conjugated as masu form without the masu part.

Comment: Are you just asking about なり or about the whole of 高くなり. Do either of these links help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41133/masu-stem-to-connect-sentences https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23796/7944

Comment: Thanks form your answers. I'm asking about the whole word "takakunari" . I guess those two links you provided  answer my question.