# Construction behind 「やり」in this sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs

> 「それはわしが**やり**おまえが追いつめられたのでわしの攻撃と同じ事！」

I am having trouble with the「**やり**」in this sentence.
I believe that it is a verb  and possibly takes the same tense as 「**追いつめられた**」(similar to verbs linked via the "て-form" or similar ways)

Long story short, my question is which grammatical construction is behind that sentence.

Comment: 連用形/masu-stem of やる (to do). Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41133/masu-stem-to-connect-sentences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「それはわしがやりおまえが追いつめられたのでわしの攻撃と同じ事！」

Allow me to first insert a couple of commas for easier reading.

> 「それはわしが**やり**、おまえが追{お}いつめられたので、わしの攻撃{こうげき}と同{おな}じ事{こと}！」

This is a 100% informal **spoken** line; therefore, a serious analysis of its grammatical construction may or may not prove very productive.  So, I will try to keep it light.

「やり」 is the 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") of the verb 「やる」 meaning "to do".  As you can see, the sentence still continues after the 「やり」.

「やり」, in this sentence, is tense-less as far as its physical form (as there is no 連用形 for verbs in past tense to begin with), but the action certainly took place in the past.  Thus, it means "**やった and then**" here, and that in turn means the same thing as 「やって」.

**Cause**: わしがそれをやった "I did it", "I am the one who did it."

**Effect**: おまえが追いつめられた "You were up against the wall."

**Conclusion** (in speaker's opinion): わしの攻撃と同じ事  "It is the same thing as my attack", "I should get the credit as my attack."

Hope this makes sense.  If this is from a game, I know nothing about games.

Comment: It is from 「ジョジョの奇妙な冒険」, so I guess it is at the same level of "formality" as most games. The last part 「わしの攻撃と同じ」really only makes sense in the context of what happened earlier (I don't think I can explain it fully here, but in short: The opponent of the speaker used the same "item" (used by the speaker himself earlier) to attack the speaker, so I think with 「わしの攻撃と同じ事 」means that what is happening now is the same "(type of) attack" that was used by the speaker earlier. In any case your explanation cleared up the issues I had with this sentence.