# ます Verb Stem + another verb grammar meaning?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I was practicing writing and got corrected by a few native speakers. They all had a correction in common where they took the ます Verb Stem and then just added a different verb on the back.

What grammar rule is going on here? What does it mean? When can I use it and when can't I use it?

My sentences were about cats. The portion I was corrected on was:

> If you don't, they won't stop screaming.

Correction A:

> あなたがそうしないなら彼らは**鳴きやみません**。
>
> My translation:
>
> If you don't, they won't stop crying (as in making animal noises).

Correction B:

> あなたがもしやめなければ彼らは**叫び続けます**。
>
> My translation:
>
> If you don't stop, they will continue to scream.

I am not sure if the person that gave me correction b understood what I meant in the first half of the sentence. But the grammar point I don't understand was still used (叫び続けます) in the second half.

Comment: There is no simple answer for this.  Most of the time they're just compound verbs that you'll have to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In verb conjugations, beginning students are typically taught only a single usage for a verb conjugation.  Base-II (or ます form) conjugation, or the い conjugation, is commonly taught as the form that is used for the ます form of verbs.  While this is true, the ます form is *not* the only usage that it has.

One of the more common usages for base-II conjugation is for combining or linking verbs and phrases.  Usually this is taught as one of the functions of the base-て conjugation, as this form of verb linking is most common, but [it can also be done with base-II conjugation](https://imulat.com/japanese/blog/how_to_connect_two_verbs_in_japanese).  To link verbs using base-II conjugation simply:

1. Conjugate the verb to the base-II (or ます) form.
2. Use the next verb *or phrase*.

Examples:

> 食べ変える (to switch food items (to eat))  --see note
>   歩き続ける (to continue walking) 
>   友達を呼び、外食に行く (call on a friend and go out to eat)

The difference between using the ます form of the て form conjugation is mostly in the formality conveyed in the sentence.  If you are talking to a superior, be it at work, school, or politics, you would do well to use the ます form to link the phrases, [as it is more formal or literary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41133/masu-stem-to-connect-sentences).

Note:

It should be noted that sometimes, when liking two verbs directly like this, the result can be someone unpredictable.  There is a plethora of verbs that, though combined in this way, do not have the expected meaning. For example:

行く (to go) + 成る  (to become) = [行き成り](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8D%E6%88%90%E3%82%8A) (abrupt; without warning)

---

This was not asked in the question, but I think that it should be addressed.

With regard to correction A:

> あなたが**そうしないなら**彼らは鳴きやみません。

While grammatically correct, I think that there is a nuance that needs to be addressed.  [Using なら](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals) as an 'if' typically carries the feeling of, "If it is true that ____, then ____."  What comes before なら in this case is usually assumed or hypothetical.

What you are talking about here isn't hypothetical, it's more certain.  In this case I would use と as your 'if.'  It carries a more certain "If ____, then ____" relationship.

> あなたが**そうしないと**彼らは鳴きやみません。

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, especially about なら part