# Why is there a し in 嫉妬し蹴落とそうとする?

Tags: meaning, words, etymology, conjugations, sentence

Hi I found a sentence earlier with 嫉妬し蹴落とそうとする and I do not know why し is put there. Anyway, I thought it was the reasoning marker but it does not sound like it from the audio and I don't know what 蹴落とそうとする means. I got a rough translation meaning 'to kick' but I might be wrong. This sentence was from oregairu season 1 ep. 1 when someone was basically criticizing the mc.

弱くて醜くて すぐに嫉妬し蹴落とそうとする

Answer (score 3):

> [嫉妬]{しっと}し [蹴落]{けお}とそうとする

The し in 嫉妬し is the continuative form (連用形) of する. In other words, 嫉妬し is the continuative form (連用形) of 嫉妬する, "envy, be jealous".

The continuative form of a verb/adjective can function as a conjunction to connect verb/adjectival phrases or sentences. Your sentence can be rephrased using the てform, as in 嫉妬し**て**蹴落とそうとする, without changing the meaning. For more on this usage of the continuative form, please see:

- [Is there a term for using conjugating verbs such that the sentence continues with another clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/9831)
- [Masu stem to connect sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41133/9831)

蹴落とそう is the volitional form of 蹴落とす, "kick down". "Volitional form + と + する" means "try to do...". For more on this grammar, please see:

- [Volitional + と + Verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9688/9831)