# Can you use the し particle without dictionary forms?

Tags: renyōkei

日本は集団主義、序列社会である。ものを大事にし、他者への配慮、思いやりを理解すべし

I'm struggling to work out the precise function of the し in ものを大事にし here.

Well - I'm quite sure it is the し particle for linking clauses, but the lack of a dictionary form before it is putting me off.

Surely it should be ものを大事にするし?

I get お大事に is an expression - that means it would just get the し at the end with nothing in between? (I would have thought [NOUN]を大事に would be different seeing as though it is different..

Comment: Duplicate/related: [Masu stem to connect sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41133/masu-stem-to-connect-sentences); [Do I have a good grasp on the basics of what the continuative form is?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65936/do-i-have-a-good-grasp-on-the-basics-of-what-the-continuative-form-is).

Answer (score 2):

し is the 連用形 of する. The 連用形 is often used as a conjunctive like the て form, but is more formal.