# Grammar use of され in sentence

Tags: grammar

I'd like to understand the use of され in the following sentence:

期限を過ぎると、仮登録したデータは自動消去され、登録したアカウントは無効になりますので、ご注意ください。

What's going on here? Is this the verb される but with the て dropped?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41133/masu-stem-to-connect-sentences) help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it does. So され is the stem of 為れる, which can be used when connecting sentences, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, for formal writing only.

Answer (score 0):

You have one sentence as

仮登録したデータは自動消去されます。

Instead of ending it, you want to continue with another sentence.  That's why you end the sentence with 「され」

So it's pretty much like you are saying in English

Temporary data being automatically erased, an account you register will become invalid.

Additionally, just as you say, you can also say

仮登録したデータは自動消去されて登録したアカウントは無効になりますので

In this case, 「て」connects two sentences.